# Best point to intercept the rendering of a page in a WebView?

Tags: android, http, post, webview

I'm writing an app that uses a WebView. Unfortunately the pages we are  loading needs a complex authentication and so we like to

1. intercept the login page. Have it processed (so cookies are stored etc..)
2. don't render it
3. POST the correct user credentials without having the user type them in the webView.

I have it running using a `WebViewClient` and overriding `override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView?, url: String?)`

Inside I check if the URL is the login form, and do a post `webView.postUrl` with the data.

It works, but the login page is displayed briefly. Is there a better way to intercept the page being rendere *before* rendering, and doing another `load`?

Thanks
W

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look at the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` callback.

You will be able to catch the url before the page is shown.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like the WebView, cookieManager etc to do their processing, before displaying anything. I think the hook `shouldOverrideUrlLoading() ` is called before loading the given url. I'd like to intercept the point where the page (or the headers at least) have been read, before processing and displaying the page